# What to write in my Dockerfile so I can properly create a container from my Flask app that uses a .Dll library

Tags: docker

Hope you are having a nice day.

So I have encountered a difficulty with uploading my Flask app on the web using Heroku, because my app uses a .DLL library, and Heroku's server are using Linux as their OS, so .DLL seems not to be compatible.

Now I have read online that Dockerfile allows you to bypass this limitation by creating a container that somehow can be ran on any OS.

The Dockerfile topic is new to me. I need some help about what Instructions to write in my Dockerfile to boot the Flask app while having the .DLL library into memory.

Here is what I currently have in the Dockerfile. It doesn't work. What should I write in there?

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev

# We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Usually Dockerfiles achieve their portability by way of the Docker Desktop application providing a hidden Linux virtual machine.  That means you'd have to find a Linux (`.so`) build of your library.  That's the same problem you're trying to resolve for your hosting service, so Docker may not be necessary for you.